# Running SQL Queries against Azure SQL with the replacement for Transient Fault Handling without using EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, entity-framework-6

When accessing Azure SQL and running queries in the pastI have used the techniques outlined in this article: [Using the Transient Fault Handling Application Block with SQL Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680899%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). According to a note at the top of the article

> This content and the technology described is outdated and is no longer
>   being maintained. For more information, see Transient Fault Handling.

That article has this information:

> Important: Recent versions of SDKs for both Azure Storage and Azure
>   Service Bus natively support retries. It is recommended to use these
>   instead of the Transient Fault Handling Application Block

From my searching it seems that the retry logic has been moved into Entity Framework and is called [Connection Resiliency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency).

I would like to use this without Entity Framework. Initially I would like to execute raw SQL against the database. When using the Reliable SQL Connection I was able to use it with a variety of ORM's because when it was set up I could just pass in the Sql Connection which was internally wrapped with the transient fault block.

How does one use the Connection Resiliency without EF? Or if that is not possible, what is the new Microsoft approved best practice for Accessing SQL Azure and dealing with transient faults?

Comment: Do take a look at [`SqlAzureExecutionStrategy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlazureexecutionstrategy(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: Thank you. Why don't you have a go at answering the question and show one how they would go about executing sql queries with this? And it is a part of EF as well, how do you use this without using EF to access SQL?  And answer as an answer, comments are for use to communicate with the OP  to gain clarification or explain something.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't used this personally thus I am not qualified to  put as an answer. I remembered answering a similar question a long time ago (it was about creating transient errors on demand) and looked it up based on the thinking that it might be useful to you.

Comment: You can read here: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-connectivity-issues.md, section ".NET SqlConnection parameters for connection retry". There are couple of parameters you can set in connection string (starting from .NET 4.5) to help with automatic retries, but that is not exactly the same as retry strategies you mentioned). But that seems all what is "Microsoft approved" for that matter.

Comment: Though you can reuse SqlAzureExecutionStrategy, because it has simple Execute method to run arbitrary block of code with retry (which will handle azure-specific transient exceptions and retry that block of code if necessary), but I cannot name that "Microsoft approved solution".